# Confused about Expressjs / Nodejs Request - Response handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dom-events

Well - the more I read the more confused I get. So here the source:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , server = express()
  ;

var home = require('./routes/home.js')
  , about = require('./routes/about.js')
  , contact = require('./routes/contact.js');

  server.configure(function () {
  server.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  server.set('view engine', 'hjs');
  server.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  server.use(express.logger());
  server.use(server.router);
  server.use(express.favicon());
  server.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
  server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  server.use(express.bodyParser());
  server.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
  server.use(express.methodOverride());
  server.use(express.session());
});

server.get('*', function (req, res) {
  switch (req.path) {

    case '/':
      res.render('home', { title:'Home Page' });
      break;

    case '/about/':
      res.render('home', { title:'About Page' });
      break;

    case '/contact/':
      res.render('contact', { title:'Contact Page' });
      break;

    default:
      res.render('home', { title:'404 - Page not found'});
  }
});
```

Well it's working, but I still don't get that req/res combo into my skull.
I'm pretty sure I don't need `'*'` there as a parameter. However I don't know how to
build up a better solution. Any simple dumb stupid exmaples so I could visualize how
exactly the magic works.

To simplify my riddle I'd like to know (and understand) why this works:

```
server.get('*', function (req, res) {
```

but this doesn't

```
server.get(function (req, res) {
```

the first parameter is always being handled as what exectly?

Comment: This doesn't look like Express at all to me. You haven't even defined `req` and `res` anywhere, so I'm surprised it even works. Take a look at the examples: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples

Comment: i don't want to post the whole thing.

Comment: Sorry - you were right I posted the wrong thing! Just reedited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the first parameter is the route.  You can break up your code into the following which might make more sense, and would follow convention:

```
server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home', { title:'Home Page' });
})

server.get('/contact/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('contact', { title:'Contact Page' });
});

server.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.render('Page Not Found', 404);
});
```

And so forth...

The `'*'` that you are using just accepts all routes.  Similar to a wildcard!

Comment: Yeah, but following convention does not bring understanding so far ;)

Comment: so you still don't get what the first parameter is?

Comment: .get method 1st param is a route name for express to parse

Comment: But handling all other routes as 404 = '*' Isn't also the best way. I mean if a non existing route is requested - forward to /404. How would you handle non existing paths in req?

Comment: If you have defined the route, express will find it.  If not it falls under '*'.  So this is how you would handle non existing path.